# Can gcc be configured to compile position-independent code for the code but position-dependent code for the data?

Tags: gcc, embedded, position-independent-code

I'm trying to build bootable code for an ARM M7-based embedded system that is able to execute in place at two different locations in the QSPI, so that if one version gets corrupted, the backup version of the image can be executed in a different place.

Compiling with -fpic seems to produce a relocatable code image that is (nearly) able to execute in both places fine. However, the problem is that the data/bss the code refers to is *also* getting offset by the same amount - that is, the compiler is assuming that the .data and .bss segments live immediately after the .text segment, which isn't true for XIP embedded systems (where the RAM is separate).

As a result, if the original binary was linked to run at 0x60000000 (and using a fixed ram area at 0x20000000) but is then executed in place at 0x60100000 instead , the ram addresses will be shifted by 0x100000 as well (i.e. to 0x20100000), which isn't what I want at all.

Clearly, what I'd like to do is to modify gcc's behaviour so that references to the code (executing in place in two different places in the QSPI) are position-independent, while references to the .data/bss segments (in a fixed position in RAM) are position-dependent (as per normal).

Is this something that gcc can be tweaked to achieve (e.g. by some obscure linker attribute flag)? Or is this just out of its reach? Thanks!

Comment: "Compiler is assuming" This statement is not correct. can you share linker file please.

Comment: Position independent code generation should have no impact on the location of data.  Your assertion seems implausible - include your evidence.  You might simply build the code twice with different start addresses.